# Can I create monitoring alerts for azure event grid domain topics?

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I would like to setup following alerts for domain topics when

- Delivery Failed Events (at domain) exceed x in y amount of time
- Delivery Failed Events (at domain topic 1) exceed x in y amount of time
- Delivery Failed Events (at domain topic 2) exceed x in y amount of time

The reason why I want the domain topic granularity is that topic 1 customer may be fine but topic 2 customer may be having issues. So customer (for topic 2) is down currently and is in extended outage period (that may last more than a day). So I want to be able to disable the alert for topic 2 only and would like to enable it once customer (for topic 2) is up and running again. Meanwhile, I want to have all other topic level alerts enabled.

I did not see a way to configure the above in the portal. Is it possible (or not) to configure above at this time in any other way? If so, can please provide the direction on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

The AEG provides durable delivery for each event message at least once to each subscriber based on its subscription. More details can be found in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry).
In the case, when the AEG can not successfully deliver a message after retrying, the dead-lettering feature (configured for each subscriber) can be used for notification and/or analyzing process via a storage eventing, where a dead-letter message is stored.

On the **publisher side**, the publisher received a standard Http response from the event domain endpoint immediately after its posting, see more details in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/post-to-custom-topic).

The current version of the AEG is not integrated to the *Diagnostic settings* (for instance, like it is done for Event Hubs) which will be enabled to push the metrics and/or logs to the stream pipeline for their analyzing process.

However, as a workaround for that, the [Azure Monitoring REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/rest-api-walkthrough) can help you. 
Using [Lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list) the metrics values for event domain, we can obtained the metrics for topics such as *Publish Succeeded*, *Publish Failed* and *Unmatched*.
the following is an example of the REST Get:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{myId}/resourceGroups/{myRG}/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/domains/{myDomain}/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2018-01-01&interval=PT1M&aggregation=none&metricnames=PublishSuccessCount,PublishFailCount,PublishSuccessLatencyInMs,DroppedEventCount
```

Based on the polling technique, you can push the event domain metrics values to the stream pipeline for their analyzing, monitoring, alerting, etc. using an Azure Stream Analytics job. Your management requirements (for instance, publisher_topic1 is disabled, etc.) can be referenced to the input stream job.

Note, that the event domain metrics didn't give a topic granularity and also there is no an activity event log at that level. I do recommend to use the [AEG feedback page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909934-azure-event-grid).